# Pass method = "post" in button and not in form

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a variable but for that I need to create a form. But I am using `JavaScript` to open the next page (that is a block page)

but I want to pass the `method="post"` directly in the button and not in the form, because it does not recognise the code.

Here is an example:

```
 <form action="" method="post"> 
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('id144').style.display='block'" class="btn btn-warning">
      Editar nome grupo
   </button>
 </form>
```

What I want:

```
<button //pass method = post here onclick="document.getElementById('id144').style.display='block'" class="btn btn-warning">
  Editar nome grupo
</button>
```

Comment: `<button //pass method = post` - I don't get what you want to do, but guessing..................... ajax?

Comment: *"but I want to pass the method="post" directly in the button"* - You can't. Buttons don't use methods; period. You can fire a function though.

Comment: *"because it does not recognize the code"* - sorry but your question is way too unclear and too broad. In any case, you've an answer below; see that. Which is what I said above in comments but you either ignored them or left the question.

Comment: I whatn to pass from POST a variable on click of the button

Comment: again; see the answer posted below. it's out of my hands.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" id="formname" method="post"> 

</form>    
<button onclick="document.getElementById('formname').submit();document.getElementById('id144').style.display='block';" class="btn btn-warning">Editar nome grupo</button>
```

Set form id.